# #ERROR on =IIf(DCount [...] with Alphanumeric field

Tags: ms-access, vba, dcount

I am using a DCOUNT function to look at a table in access and see if a record exists - if it does then return a yes value.

```
=IIf(DCount("*","COMMENTS","[PROJECTID] = " & [PROJECTID])>0,"YES","")
```

This works great if my ProjectID is all numeric values - I only get #Error on the alphanumeric values.

I know that I have to make the ProjectID criteria a string but am having trouble placing the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, break out the `DCount` piece and work on that by itself.

It sounds like your *COMMENTS.PROJECTID* field is text datatype, so add quotes before and after the value you concatenate into the third `DCount` argument (*Criteria*):

```
DCount("*", "COMMENTS", "[PROJECTID] = '" & [PROJECTID] & "'")
```

After you have that piece working correctly, add it into your `IIf()` function.

Comment: Thanks HansUp - that led me in the right direction
`=IIf(DCount("*","COMMENTS","[ProjectID] = '" & [ProjectID] & "'")>0,"YES","")` ended up being what used